# How to do a case-insensitive search on a keyword field in Elasticsearch without reindexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a keyword field like this:

```
"address": {
   "type": "keyword"
}
```

The value is written in camel-case, as it's intended for display. e.g "1/10 Somewhere Rd, Somewhere AAA 3333"

Now, i want to do a case-insensitive *search* on that field, ideally **without reindexing the entire index**.

What i've found so far is that [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) can be used for case-insensitive search, but only works on `text` fields.

Is my only option reindexing, e.g via a `text` field, or using a lowercase/custom normalizer/analyser? Any way i can do it *without* reindexing?

Comment: @Opster thanks for the answer, but it's stuff I already knew rather than an actual answer to the question. But I accepted as answer for completeness.. thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right that `match` queries can be used for case-insensitive search as it applied the same analyzer which was used at index time but works only for `text` field.

Problem here is that while indexing, as you have used `keyword` field, so tokens in elasticsearch inverted index, which is used to match the tokens of search query are not `lowercased` so it is not possible at all to provide case-insensitive search.

Let's understand above statement using an example:

Let's suppose you have `Foo BAR` in your document, which you indexed using `keyword` field. **Please note the case of each character**, so inverted index will have below token.

`Foo BAR`, now at query time by some hook or crook, you can convert search term to either all uppercase or lowercase but in this case still it won't match the tokens, so you will still have a lot of issues in search results.

**I would suggest, add a new field which uses `text` and using [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) create a fresh index and implement it in clean manner**, also using reindex API, you can build a new index from old index, and its much faster to build a new index, rather than build from source of truth(SQL in most cases).

Comment: it's possible to add a new field, let's say "lowercase", to your keyword field with a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) which takes the [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html). You would then base your queries on this lowercase field rather than the main keyword field

Answer (score 0):

As of version 7.10, the [Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-field-params) supports a `case_insensitive` parameter

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user.id": {
        "value": "kimchy",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, as of v8.10 the [Terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) does not support `case_insensitive`.

The best approach I've found is [this](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/search-apis/elasticsearch-lowercase-analysis/) that uses a normalizer which lowercases the string at index time. That way you can use any query that supports normalization and get case insensitive matches.